# Angular 2 testcomponentbuilder does not work with several directives from third party libraries

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I am writing unit tests for my angular 2 component with Jasmine framework and somehow Jasmine always skips my spec if I include directives not from the angular original module (in my case the test only works with directives for example from angular/core and angular/common). This is my app component:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NgStyle} from '@angular/common';
import { CollapseDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/collapse';
import {MdButton} from '@angular2-material/button';
import { MdDataTable } from 'ng2-material';
import { EntityFilterPipe } from './entity-filter.pipe';
import { NgFor } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: 'app/entity.html',
    pipes: [EntityFilterPipe],
    directives: [NgStyle, NgFor, CollapseDirective]
})
export class EntityTestComponent implements OnInit {
    public title = 'Entities';
    @Input() name:string;
    showSearch: boolean = true;
    listFilter:string;
    toggleSearch(): void {
        this.showSearch = !this.showSearch;
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("printed");
    }
}
```

And this is my spec:

```
import {describe,
    it,
    beforeEach,
    inject,
    expect,
    beforeEachProviders
} from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ComponentFixture, TestComponentBuilder } from '@angular/compiler/testing';
import { EntityTestComponent } from './entity-test.component';

export function main() {
    describe('Entity component', () => {
        let tcb: TestComponentBuilder;
        beforeEachProviders(() => [TestComponentBuilder, EntityTestComponent]);
        beforeEach(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (_tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
            tcb = _tcb
        }));

        it('should display no item found when item is not on the list', done => {
            //expect(true).toBe(true);
            tcb.createAsync(EntityTestComponent).then(fixture => {
                let property = fixture.componentInstance;
                expect(property.showSearch).toBe(true);
                done();
            })
                .catch(e => done.fail(e));
        });
```

The spec is run if I only include NgStyle and NgFor in my list directives. When I tried including anything from different libraries, such as CollapseDirective or MdDataTable, the spec is skipped -- jasmine test does not show success or failure. Any suggestion is much appreciated!
Thanks